# Setting connection timeout for Spring Integration SFTP

Tags: java, spring, connection, integration, sftp

Is it possible to set connection timeout for Spring integration SFTP?

```
<bean id="defaultSftpSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
    <property name="host" value=""/>
    <property name="privateKey" value=""/>
    <property name="privateKeyPassphrase" value=""/>
    <property name="port" value=""/>
    <property name="user" value=""/>
    <property name="serverAliveInterval" value="100000"/>
    <property name="serverAliveCountMax" value="5"/>
    <property name="timeout" value="100000"/>
</bean>
```

**serverAliveInterval**, **serverAliveCountMax** and **timeout** doesn't make any difference what's related to connection timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Several common properties are exposed on the session factory (since version 4.0, this now includes connectTimeout, defaultTimeout and dataTimeout)

See document [ftp-session-factory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-session-factory)